# What is this small red fruit with a passion fruit like pulp inside?

Tags: identification, fruit-trees

Can anyone identify this fruit?  Its ripening now, which is early autumn here in New Zealand.

[image]

[image]

Comment: what size is the fruit and the tree?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on the way the fruit is clustered, and similarly the way the leaves are clustered. I think what you have is *[Psidium cattleyanum](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Psidium_cattleyanum)*. Common names include: Cattley guava, strawberry guava, and cherry guava.

There's a similar type, *[Ugni molinae](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Ugni_molinae)* (chiliean quava), but I think the fruits look more like cherries as they have longer stems.

Strawberry guava fruit are edible (including the skin), though I think they're most commonly used for jellies/jams rather than eating plain. Here are some pictures I found for comparison (click them for more).

[image]
[image]

Comment: that's the one!  very nice :)

Answer (score 2):

That looks a lot like mangosteen, though it would be easier to be sure if it was peeled rather than sliced.

Never had decent ones in the USA; it's a very unique flavor.

**Edit based on comments:** Marble-sized - yeah, probably not mangosteen. As for pomegranate, not nearly enough seeds, I'd think, though perhaps at that scale it's a reasonable number - never seen them that small, but I don't know how small they grow that simply don't show up in markets.

Comment: think scale might be at issue here,  just googled mangosteen, they seem quite big.  The fruit in the picture are aout the size of marbles

Comment: unripened pomegranate?